# How do I implement a sign-in process?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ember.js

I am trying to understand authentication with Ember. Correct me if I am wrong with this flow:

```
1) User fills out a form
2) Form is submitted to app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb (create action)
3) Create action creates the user, and sets the Rails session for the user
```

Up to this point, all works well.

I am stuck with the idea on how to allow users to sign in. This is what I understand so far:

```
1) User fills out sign in form (email and password)
2) Form is submitted to app/controllers/api/v1/sessions_controller.rb (create action)
3) Rails creates the session for the user
```

When the user moves from page to page, what should I be doing at this point? Should Ember contact the Rails API to determine if the user is signed in by sending over the cookie information?

Or should Ember just look at the cookie and nothing else?